# Multi Level Responsive Menu ... Transiction between mobile and non mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a multilevel responsive menu: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/FrIbq

1 - By placing the mouse over "content" item a sub menu will appear;

2 - When resizing the menu to mobile size a Menu link will appear and the menu disappears.

So far so good ... What is missing is:

A - When clicking in Menu link the menu should become visible or invisible;

B - When one of the submenus is clicked then its child ul should become visible or invisible.

Of course (A) and (B) should be only mobile version, so width less than 800px.

I tried to solve it using enquire.js: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/alxkI. So I have:

```
$('nav a[href="#"]').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 800px)", {
    match: function () {
      $('nav a[href="#"]').on('click.match', function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
      })
    },
    unmatch: function () {
      $('nav a[href="#"]').off('click.match');
    }
});
```

But I get problems when resizing from Mobile version and not Mobile version ...

Could someone help me out? Using Enquire or not ...

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like, the trouble here was with loading enquire from github.

I've changed the source of enquire.js to load it from my domain temporary.
Here's a working [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ernAg)

**Update:**
Instead of using jQuery toggle, use class `.expanded {display: block;}` toggle on click. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oHyxK

Comment: Not really ... Try the menu in big screen. You will see that it works fine. Resize it to mobile. It works fine to ... Now resize back to big screen ... Now it stopped working ... That is the problem I am not able to explain ... Any idea?

Comment: Of course :) You're using jQuery toggle which adds an inline style `display:none` to your dropdown. It has higher priority and isn't being removed in `unmatch` method. You might also want to add classes to your `ul`-s (e.g. `nav-ul`, `inner-dropdown`) to clean up your LESS a bit.

Comment: What do you suggest in the JQuery part instead of the toogle? I am not sure how to do it. Could you give me an example? About the LESS: what are the advantages of using the CSS classes?

Comment: I'd suggest adding/removing class on click `.expanded {display: block;}` - [Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oHyxK).

Regarding using classes instead of tag selectors - too huge topic to cover within a comment. Take a look at those reads:
[Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS),

[idiomatic CSS](https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css),

[GitHub CSS Style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/css).

It'll also improve readibility of your code a lot, it's hard for a third person to keep track of all nested selectors, while reading.